# How do I make the output to be "Avocado Roll, Salmon Temaki, California Roll, Miso Soup" etc.. I do not know how to use subtring method properl

Tags: java, substring

Hi can you please help me with the substring method I do not know how to capitalise specific words only

```
private static void viewAllItems(ArrayList<Item> itemList) {

        // TODO: P05 Task 3 - Write code here to displays all items from the ArrayList of Item objects
        // passed to it.

        itemList = load();

        String output = String.format("%-20s %-10s\n", "ITEM", "PRICE");

        for (Item i : itemList) {
            String a = String.format("%s", i.getType().toUpperCase().split(""));


            output += String.format("%-20s  %-10.2f\n", a.concat(i.getType().substring(1).toLowerCase() ), i.getPrice());

        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

I expected output

Avocado Roll
Salmon Temaki
California Roll
Miso Soup

but I got 
Avocado roll
Salmon temaki
California roll
Miso soup

Answer (score 1):

Your code capitalizes only first letter for each item type:

avocado roll -> Avocado roll

I would suggest the following code:

```
for (Item item : itemList) {
  String[] words = item.getType().split("\\s"); // splits into words

  for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)) + words[i].substring(1); // capitalizes first letter of each word
  }

  output += String.format("%-20s  %-10.2f\n", String.join(" ", words), item.getPrice());
}
```